# Ruby on Rails - passing id from a model to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, global-variables

I have two models, `Appointment` and `Intervention` (Appointment belongs_to Intervention   and Intervention has_one Appointment)

On the index view of the `Appointment` I have a link to `new_Intervention_path`

If the new intervention is created I want to set the status of the `Appointment` to DONE (it was previously PENDING) and assign the id of the new Intervention to the appointment.intervention_id field.

How can I pass the id of the appointment to the intervention controller so that I can make this happen?

--EDIT---

this is the index view of the model `Appointment`

```
<h1>Listing appointments</h1>

<table>
 <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Mes</th>
    <th>Ano</th>
    <th>Agendado</th>
    <th>Observacoes</th>
    <th>Addendum</th>
    <th>Intervention</th>
    <th>Appointment state</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
  <% @appointments.each do |appointment| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= appointment.dataprovavel.mon %></td>
      <td><%= appointment.dataprovavel.year %></td>
      <td><%= appointment.dataagendado %></td>
      <td><%= appointment.observacoes %></td>
      <td><%= appointment.addendum.numero %></td>
      <td><%= appointment.intervention_id %></td>
      <td><%= appointment.appointment_state.descricao %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', appointment %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_appointment_path(appointment) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', appointment, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'New Intervention', new_intervention_path%></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I added the `link_to 'New Intervention', newintervention_path`

This is `Intervention` controller
ATTENTION: this is code is WRONG, I'm just attempting to explain what I prettend

```
class InterventionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
@intervention = Intervention.new(intervention_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @intervention.save
    format.html { redirect_to @intervention, notice: 'Intervention was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @intervention }
    updateAppointment
  else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @intervention.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

def updateAppointment
  Appointment.find(appointment_id).appointment_state_id = 1
end
```

I want that the variable `appointment_id` used on the Addendum Controller to store the Appointment ID from the Index View of the Appointment

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to do. You might need to show some of the code from your view

Comment: I will post the later ( I can't do it just now) but what I want is when the Intervention is created I want to update the status of the Appointment that created the intervention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find an answer to my problem, just don't know if it's the best one.

On the view `Appointment/index.html.erb` I added the following link_to

```
<td><%= link_to 'New Intervention', new_intervention_path(:appointment_id => appointment.id)%></td>
```

where I send the appointment_id through the url

On the form of the new Intervention ( `interventions\_form.html.erb` ) I added an hidden field like:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :appointment_id, :value => params[:appointment_id]%>
```

on the action CREATE of the Intervention's Controller `interventions_controller.rb` I added the following code:

```
def create

@appointment = Appointment.find(params[:intervention][:appointment_id])
@intervention = Intervention.new(intervention_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @intervention.save
    format.html { redirect_to @intervention, notice: 'Intervention was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @intervention }
    activateAppointment
  else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @intervention.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

def activateAppointment
  @appointment.appointment_state = AppointmentState.where(description:'Done').first
  @appointment.intervention_id = @intervention.id
  @appointment.save
end
```